как спарсить последнее обновление игры стим
как спарсить последнее обновление игры стим? с помощью beautifulsoup, python

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Зайти в Steam и обновить игру.
